# Intelli j - running a task after a file save

Tags: intellij-idea

Im using Intellij IDEA 13 and I'd love to have a sh script file to be executed as soon as I save a file. Any ideashow to do this ? I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Are you aware that in Idea files are saved automatically, there is no need to save them manually?

Comment: yes .. i want to launch a background process also

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a good idea, because your files are saved very often, and this script could have a performance impact on your machine. Perhaps it is enough to run the script automatically before a check-in into a VCS?

Anyway, if you insist, you could use external tools in order to monitor the file system for changes,

- On Windows see https://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/
- On Linux see https://superuser.com/questions/363511/execute-script-program-when-file-changes